# How to make the following script accept both uppercases & lowercases when someone clicks like alphabet A

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, alphabetical

I got this code from the Internet and tried to use in my web app. I've a WebGrid (Webmatrix) with tabular data. I need to filter the table's name field with alphabets (A, B, ... Z - all caps). But, when there is a record with a name with all lower cases, the script will not find that record. Can anybody help? Thanks

```
$(function () {
    var _alphabets = $('.alphabet > a');
    var _contentRows = $('.table-sieve tbody tr');

    _alphabets.click(function () {
        var _letter = $(this), _text = $(this).text(), _count = 0;

        _alphabets.removeClass("active");
        _letter.addClass("active");

        _contentRows.hide();
        _contentRows.each(function (i) {
            var _cellText = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
            if (RegExp('^' + _text).test(_cellText)) {
                _count += 1;
                $(this).fadeIn(400);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! We value self research and effort from posters. Have you tinkered with the code? Tried anything? You can apparently identify the problem, maybe you can have an insight on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try ignoring case in regexp call:

```
$(function () { var _alphabets = $('.alphabet > a'); var _contentRows = $('.table-sieve tbody tr');

_alphabets.click(function () {
var _letter = $(this), _text = $(this).text(), _count = 0;

_alphabets.removeClass("active");
_letter.addClass("active");

_contentRows.hide();
_contentRows.each(function (i) {
var _cellText = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
if (RegExp('^' + _text,"i").test(_cellText)) {
_count += 1;
$(this).fadeIn(400);
}
});
});

});
```